# What is the Oracle equivalent of TG_OP and TG_NAME in Postgres?

Tags: oracle, plsql, audit, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger that just inserts the name of the modified table and the operation performed on it. Kind of like:

```
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO audit_table VALUES(user,tg_name,tg_op);
 END;
```

However I can't find what's the equivalent in Oracle to `tg_name` and `tg_op` from Postgres.

Comment: Which oracle version?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100%3A11%3A0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID%3A542325000346769711

Comment: @abdelp oracle 12c

Comment: If the posted trigger code representative of what you actually want to do then you should use the built in Oracle `AUDIT` command instead. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107).

Answer (score 1):

Huh, there's nothing that simple in Oracle, as far as I can tell (but I admit - I may be very wrong and someone might know better). Anyway, until that *better* answer comes, here's a little bit of coding; see if it helps.

I'm creating a test table and a log table (though, I'm not sure how *good* your log table actually is; you don't know when something was done etc. so - I took some freedom to add at least the DATE column).

```
SQL> create table test as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL> create table test_log
  2    (username   varchar2(30),
  3     c_date     date,
  4     table_name varchar2(30),
  5     action     varchar2(1));

Table created.
```

A trigger: unfortunately, I don't know whether there's a built-in function which returns name of an object (a table, in our case) you're doing something with, so I'm querying `USER_OBJECTS`.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test_log
  2    after insert or update or delete on test
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_table_name varchar2(30);
  6    l_action     varchar2(1);
  7  begin
  8    select object_name
  9      into l_table_name
 10      from user_objects
 11      where object_id = dbms_rowid.rowid_object(nvl(:new.rowid, :old.rowid));
 12
 13    if inserting then
 14       l_action := 'I';
 15    elsif updating then
 16       l_action := 'U';
 17    elsif deleting then
 18       l_action := 'D';
 19    end if;
 20
 21    insert into test_log (username, c_date, table_name, action)
 22      values (user, sysdate, l_table_name, l_action);
 23  end;
 24  /

Trigger created.
```

And ... action!

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> delete from test where deptno = 40;

1 row deleted.

SQL> update test set loc = 'CROATIA' where deptno = 10;

1 row updated.

SQL> insert into test (deptno, dname, loc) values (99, 'STACK', 'OVERFLOW');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CROATIA
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        99 STACK          OVERFLOW

SQL> select * From test_log;

USERNAME                       C_DATE              TABLE_NAME                     A
------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------------ -
SCOTT                          23.09.2018 08:44:17 TEST                           D
SCOTT                          23.09.2018 08:44:17 TEST                           U
SCOTT                          23.09.2018 08:44:17 TEST                           I

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in having special attribute for table_name and operation in DML trigger.
DML trigger can be created only on ONE table so you can hardcode its name in trigger itself.
Conditional predicates INSERTING, DELETING, and UPDATING can be used to derive operation name.

If, howevere, you want to create schema level trigger then you can use predefined attributes ora_*.

```
create table audit_table
(
  user_name varchar2(30),
  table_name varchar2(30),
  action varchar2(30)
);

create or replace trigger schema_trigger
before create or alter
on schema
begin
  insert into audit_table
    (user_name, table_name, action)
  values
    (ora_login_user, ora_dict_obj_name, ora_sysevent);
end schema_trigger;
/
```

[PL/SQL Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm)

Comment: And that is just one (of a billion reasons) that proves that Oracle really sucks! I'll live to see this database go to ostracism!

Comment: @Christian, it's been a while but if you are reading this by any chance - could you provide a few more real-life examples of what can be done in PG and is not available in ORA?